# MySQL One-to-Many: Select where only one relations exists

Tags: mysql, select, one-to-many, where-clause, relation

My Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `binary` (
  `binaryid` int(15) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`binaryid`)
);

CREATE TABLE `binarycollection` (
  `binaryid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `collectionid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `collectionid` (`collectionid`,`binaryid`),
  KEY `binaryid` (`binaryid`)
);
```

In the binary table there can only exist one record to a binaryid.
The binarycollection table ties the binary to multiple collections.

What I need to do is make a query that will select all rows in binary that have exactly 1 relations in binarycollection.

So given the example:

```
binary:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7

binarycollection:
(binaryid    collectionid)
1   1
2   1
3   1
3   2
4   1
4   2
5   2
6   2
```

It should return binaryids 1, 2, 5, and 6.

Any help is appreciated. :)

ps. This needs to be efficient, the tables contain millions of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` :

```
Select binaryid from binarycollection group by binaryid having count(*)=1
```

Comment: @Turnkey @Jérôme Boé What about if I add another constraint, I want to limit it to a set of collectionids.

    `SELECT binaryid
    FROM binarycollection
    WHERE collectionid IN (SELECT collectionid FROM cleanup)
    GROUP BY binaryid
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1`

It fails.

Comment: You can make a JOIN with ng_cleanup table and add a clause Where.

Comment: `SELECT binaryid
FROM binarycollection
LEFT JOIN cleanup
USING ( collectionid ) 
WHERE cleanup.collectionid IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY binaryid
HAVING COUNT( * ) =1`

Still not working.

It is probably filtering by collectionid first, so the rest of the query is only seeing a single binarycollection row per binary row.

Comment: Try using some parens to help isolate the subquery into a table projection, e.g.

SELECT TABLE.binaryid FROM (SELECT binaryid, collectionID FROM binarycollection WHERE collectionid IN (SELECT collectionid FROM cleanup)) TABLE GROUP BY TABLE.binaryid HAVING COUNT(binaryid) = 1

Comment: I managed to make it work using this code: `SELECT binaryid, collectionid
FROM ng_binarycollection
GROUP BY (
binaryid
)
HAVING COUNT( * ) = 1
) AS binarycollection2` but it seems inefficient to me, to select _ALL_ rows that only contain a single binarycollection entry _THEN_ filter it by collectionid, when the collectionid would really drop the number of rows.

Comment: That query should have read `SELECT binaryid
FROM (
 SELECT binaryid, collectionid
        FROM ng_binarycollection
        GROUP BY (binaryid)
        HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) AS binarycollection2
WHERE collectionid IN (
 SELECT collectionid
        FROM ng_cleanup
)`

Answer (score 1):

It should work out to a simple query since your referential integrity doesn't allow repeat pairs in the binarycollection table:

```
SELECT binaryid 
FROM binarycollection
GROUP BY binaryid
HAVING ( COUNT(binaryid) = 1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

`join` it with the original `binary` table to check for valid reference then `group` the `binaryID`

```
SELECT  a.binaryid
FROM    `binary` a 
            INNER JOIN `binarycollection` b
                on a.binaryid = b.binaryid
GROUP BY a.binaryid
HAVING  COUNT(a.binaryid) = 1
```